# Comparing an element from an array of structs and a string

Tags: struct, error-handling, boolean-logic

My code is below. I have created a phone book from an input file, loaded it up, read it and assigned the file to a struct with .fname .lname .phone. The method which i though should work would take user input, clear the buffer afterwards and then compare the specific element of the struct with the user input and check if they are equal by using a forloop to cycle through each struct.

The problem as I found through debug is that I the string is never shown to be equal. It just skips to "no contacts found". Ii checked and the user input gets assigned correctly, but boolean condition is never satisfied. Maybe I can't do contacts.lname ==lastnameSearch

Also to note, the first printf statement is to verify that the elements of the array were what i expected them to. I never enter most inner if statement. There are no compiler errors.

Code(I can post my entire code if someone needs that):

```
  else if (choice == 3)
            {
                char lastnameSearch[50];
                printf("\n\nEnter the last name of the person you are looking for.\n");
                scanf("%s", lastnameSearch);
                fgetc(stdin);
                int k=0;
                for(k=0; count>k; k++)
                {
                    printf("%s %s", contacts[k].fname, contacts[k].lname);
                    if(contacts[k].lname==lastnameSearch)
                    {
                        printf("\n\nFirst name:\t%s. \nLast Name:\t%s. \nPhone Number:\t%s.\n\n ", contacts[k].fname, contacts[k].lname, contacts[k].phone);
                    }
                }
                printf("\nContact not found.\n\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempt to compare 2 string values with a mathematical comparison operator.
Have a look at strcmp function, which is what is primarily used for string comparison in C.
It returns 0 if both string matches, else >0 or <0, dependent upon the ASCII value total of the strings from memory.

But for your issue, just go with:

```
if (strcmp(contacts[k].lname, lastnameSearch) == 0) {
    // Match found
}
else {
    // No match
}
```

Comment: You're right... I don't know why I though a string could be compared numerically now that I think of it... I should know better.

Comment: One last question, just as a maybe if you know the answer:

How could I tell that boolean search to not care about capitalization? ie searching for Sarah or sarah would be the same? Does that function perform that as well or is there a separate one?

Comment: Change function to strcmpi(). That's the case insensitive version of strcmp()

Comment: Sorry, strcmpi() is C++. I get these 2 mixed up from time to time. The other simple option is tolower() every character in the string before using strcmp().